# How to automate browser session opened by an desktop app, using selenium Java?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am automating a cloud storage product. It has a desktop and web application, just like Dropbox.
The test scenario is:

1. Open the desktop app from a system tray.
2. Click on the link which opens the web application on a browser with a single sign-on.
3. Do folder rename operation on a web version of the app, and close the browser windows.

So here when a web application opens, it opens in the main browser instance which I want to automate.

I tried to use debug mode, by assigning a port. It seems this approach is not gonna help.

Comment: For desktop app you gonna need more then selenium. See https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/how-to-automate-desktops-apps-using-winappdriver/ or https://docs.katalon.com/docs/create-tests/introduction-to-test-creation/introduction-to-desktop-app-testing-in-katalon-studio. But I'm not sure if to combine WinAppDriver with WebDriver is possible.